# Nodejs install issue on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, ubuntu

I install nodejs using the following command on ubuntu

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Then it gives this message,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 253 not upgraded.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/  Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.bintray.com_sbt_debian_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

When I do "sudo apt-get update", I get another error,

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ole.wolf/rarcrack/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ole.wolf/rarcrack/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Could you please let me know what how to correct that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors occur because the four source links you (or some installer) added to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` are not found and return error 404.

If said entries are not in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you can find them in some file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`.

Delete the lines containing those urls in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or some file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`) and install Node.js the official way:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Or if you want version 6:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**Note**

Maybe your running into that problem because your Ubuntu version is not supported.
I don't think they support 15.10, but only the LTS versions (14.04 & 16.04).

If you can, upgrade to 16.04 and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Unfortunately the files does not contain the 4 urls. Do you know from where else they might be taken? Thanks again

Comment: Check the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Maybe you can find the entry there. I've just edited the post and added the other configuration file locations.